# Skype making noises loud when using headphones on a HP pavilion dv6

Tags: audio, skype, noise

Sounds made by Skype are loud when using headphones. The volume of the sound is independent of the volume control. I have tried contacted HP support but they did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway

I fixed it by updating drivers on the HP website

Then I changed the settings in Skype.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on (Vista or Win7), you can also control the volume of induvidual applications.
Click on the Speaker icon in the system tray bottom right
Click on "Mixer"
Adjust the Volume Slider for "Skype Application" (Note skype should be running, for Skype to appear in this Mixer Window.

You can also adjust Skype Sound settings, from within skype's Settings page-

Goto Skype > Tools > Options > Under General - Audio Settings
If you remove the check on "Automatically adjust speaker settings" you will now be able to control the Speaker volume from Skype

Let us know if this is what you require, or if it helps or not.

Regards,
alke2007

Comment: Nope tried that

Comment: Sorry if im late.